# How to close large gaps in real life images?

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision, edge-detection

Assume I have a picture of a real life object, for example this:

[image]

Using bilateral filtering and canny edge detection yields:

[image: /home/camilotalero/Desktop/CounterTopExperiment/image_screenshot_05.02.2019.png]

This has a high probability of not properly detecting certain edge sections

[image]

Even without bilateral filtering:

[image]

I need to increase the probability of these kinds of edges to be detected. Time is not an issue.

I have tried certain image sharpen effects but none seem to have an effect in making that edge more likely to be detected.

Edit:

I am trying to do this only for interior images and only for large flat surfaces. I am also not trying to get something perfect, i just want an over prediction that contains the border with some high probability of success (80%+)

In the specified example and other cases I have tried, the problem comes mostly due to a lack of sharpness on transitions between border regions.

Edit 2:

Extracting each channel and adding the result of canny for each of red, blue, green resulted in a closed shape.

Comment: Please try to avoid the impressoin that this is about help with using filters, instead of being a programming question. The programming question "How can I program a hitherto unknown filter for detecting the border between original and mirror and other near-human-eye feats of recognition?" is too broad.

Comment: Did you try lowering the thresholds used by Canny?

Comment: @Yunnosch I don;t want to detect the border, i want to guarantee the border is in the detection. If that makes sense. i.e I don;t mind overdetecting noise and irrelevant features, as long as the result of canny edge detection contains the edge. I am also not looking for this to work 100% of the time, 80% is probably good enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A very effective method to improve the edge detection is to run canny on each individual channel (RGB) and then add up the images using addWeighted() rather than running the detection on a grey scaled image. Converting the image to different color spaces and doing this process again also improves it further.

Answer (score 1):

In this sample, the edge vanishes close to the top left corner because the contrast becomes very low, due to the lighter background. This is virtually unrecoverable without prior information on the shape. Indeed, it might be that the true edges follow the white vertical area instead of the marble table, as occurs on the unfiltered image. We human can discriminate thanks to the color/texturing on both sides of the edge, but Canny is far from such a performance.

You may have a try with image segmentation and texture segmentation, though the latter is not readily available in OpenCV. Be aware that you are tackling a difficult problem.

Answer (score 1):

If it is your goal to close those gaps in the lines which would lead to perfectly continuous lines try to use hough transformation and line detection. Some sort of edge detection is still needed so keep canny.

The parameters will allow you to tune what to detect as line and what not. In your case detecting the table would be quite easy. Some morphological opening could help if it has problems because of the marble pattern but I doubt that.

[Here is a tutorial/ some information](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d9/db0/tutorial_hough_lines.html) from OpenCV

EDIT:

If you want to get a rectangle which is closed you might do the hough transformation by yourself. In the hough space there will be four highly dense regions. Two of those will have the same r or theta axis. That's how one can detect not only lines but also rectangles in hough space. Transforming those four point back will lead to four lines forming the rectangle (In this picture most probably the table). Maybe there is already an OpenCv hough rectangle detector. Haven't checked.